# Tailwind have scrollable center and right divs with sticky header and left side

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a email/tasks type of layout that the page has a fixed header and has a 3 columns with the left bar also be fixed and center and right bar has fixed header items, everything seems to work but as soon as you scroll on the left sidebar it still scrolls the entire page to up and down.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/gUiPZAyybX

I want the whole page to be the height of the screen and the center and right bar must scroll. Just can't seem to get the whole page to not scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `min-h-screen` for your div that's causing the scroll. You can instead give it `h-screen overflow-y-hidden` to fix the height and prevent page scroll. Here's a remix of your Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/slBgyxxOO0